# jQuery modify h1 that has a unique child

Tags: jquery

Apologies if this is a silly question, but I'm very new to jQuery and would like to know how to solve this problem;

https://jsfiddle.net/a0f7segf/1/

I'm trying to check if an 'inner' div has a child class='unique' within it (it's a span in this example). And if it does, then to change the text of the .title h1 next to this 'inner' div.

I've tried:

```
if ($(".outer .inner").has(".unique")) {
    $(".outer .title").text("jQuery has been executed");
}
```

But it modifies **all** .title elements.

*On a side note, can anyone suggest any good (in your opinion of course) sites/books to learn jQuery from?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this,

```
$(".outer .inner").has(".unique").prev(".title").text("jQuery has been executed");
```

or you can use the `:has()` selector,

```
 $(".outer .inner:has(.unique)").prev(".title").text("jQuery has been executed");
```

Also note that, `.has()` is a filter, it will not yield a boolean result

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/a0f7segf/4/)

Comment: @Ridai Glad to help! :)